# Getting duplicates while writing a function to display even/odd numbers in list?

Tags: python

```
even=[]
odd=[]
def numberCheck(listt):
    for i in listt:
        if i % 2== 0:
            even.append(i)
        else:
            odd.append(i)
    
    print(odd)
    print(even)
```

Usage:

```
numberCheck([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
-> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
-> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
numberCheck([20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,40,28,19])
-> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 19]
-> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 40, 28]
```

I'm trying to code a function to take a list of numbers and display the even and odd ones in seperate lists, but I keep getting duplicates. Up until 10, this issue doesn't occur, but after I put values over 10 in the list, I keep getting duplicates.

Comment: You keep appending to to *same lists*.

Comment: Move `even=[]` and `odd=[]` to inside the function to create new lists each time.

Comment: You need to put the odd and even lists _inside_ the function. Otherwise, the function will continue to append to those lists, and will add to the lists each call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do something like:

```
a = [0, 1, 2]
b = a
b.append(3)
print(a)
```

The output will be [0, 1, 2, 3], because python uses the same memory address for both of the lists rather than creating a new one (That is what happens with integers for example), because creating a new list is very expensive (speed / memory).

**You have to reset the list every time you call the function like so:**

```
def numberCheck(listt):
    even=[]
    odd=[]

    for i in listt:
        if i % 2== 0:
            even.append(i)
        else:
            odd.append(i)

    print(odd)
    print(even) 

numberCheck([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
numberCheck([20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,40,28,19])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm a beginner, I really appreciate it (: